# xcrun: How do we sign the application along with an extension?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, continuous-integration, xcodebuild

On our jenkins, we use the xcrun to package the application and pass the provisioning profile with `embed` option.

```
/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v "${RELEASE_BUILDDIR}/${APPLICATION_NAME}.app" -o "${BUILD_HISTORY_DIR}/${APPLICATION_NAME}.ipa" --sign "${DEVELOPER_NAME}" --embed "${PROVISONING_PROFILE}"
```

Now, we have an extension that's included with the application. How do I specify the provisioning profile to build the app with extension?